# Setting fetch size of a gremlin traversal

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, titan, tinkerpop

Is there a way to set fetch size of a gremlin traversal. I have a very complicated traversal that I am doing in gremlin. The traversal is expected to result in a large amount of nodes and the iteration is fetching these nodes in batches so a long time is spent over the network. Is there a way to provide a fetch size to gremlin so that this time can be minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an option in Gremlin itself to do that.  Control over such a thing is handled by the means by which you are executing your Gremlin.  For example, if you are using Titan with Cassandra you could change this setting:

`storage.cassandra.thrift.frame_size_mb`

which controls the maximum frame size to be used by thrift for transport. You can increase this value when retrieving very large result sets.  You can read more about other such settings [here](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-Cassandra) and in other implementation specific configuration wiki pages.

Another example, would be related to issuing your Gremlin to Rexster.  In this case, you have less options that work out of the box.  Rexster generically works best for fast request/response.  If you have traversals that you know ahead of time will be large result sets it might be better to write your own [Rexster Extension](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Extensions).  A good example to look at is how the [FaunusRexsterInputFormatExtension](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/faunus/formats/rexster/FaunusRexsterInputFormatExtension.java) works.  This extension provides a way to stream back specified portions of the entire Graph.  These are very long run operations over HTTP (on a large graph of course).  You might find that to be a good model.  .